# Windows installer won't install any assembly into GAC

Tags: windows-7, installation

If I try to install a msi, which puts any assembly into GAC, it fails with message "The signature or catalog could not be verified or is not valid", though the assembly is correctly strong signed (I can't installs official installs of common applications that writes assemblies into GAC). I have administrator privileges and I tried to run installs as administrator (no change). When I put the dll on which installers fails into GAC manually, it is added without any error. Does anyone has any idea what's wrong with windows installer that it won't add into GAC correctly signed assemblies?

Answer (score 1):

If it happens to you, open regedit, go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\StrongName and delete value "CSP" to reset CSP to default.

Comment: This is vital.  On my computer, an invalid value got into this key somehow and after that, most installers failed with "an error occurred during the installation of assembly ... the signature or catalog could not be verified or is not valid".  Once I deleted this key with sn.exe -c (both x86 and x64) *and rebooted*, the failing installers worked.